# How to secure consistency of saved Pytorch Conv1D model for time-series predictions day by day?

Tags: python, time-series, pytorch, save, load

I developed a standard Conv1D model in Pytorch to predict time series with classification (4 classes).
I gathered a train set (5000 data) and a test set (1000 data). The model predicts daily data by batches and is quite efficient.

As the results were satisfactory, I then moved to the next step :

1. I trained my model
2. I saved the model
3. I used the trained model on daily new data (bringing data for prediction day-by-day, instead of by batch size).
   The results were very deceptive (if not catastrophic).

Therefore, I checked what happen and tried to save my trained model, to clean the GPU cache, to re-load the model and to apply it to the test-set.

Herewith the original code :

```
    train_dl, test_dl = get_data_loaderRN(X_train, y_train, X_tests, y_tests, batch_size) 
    model = Conv_1D(input_shape, nb_classes, num_features, seq_length, batch_size, iter_model, iter_pre, dropout)
    model = model.double()
    model.cuda()
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()  
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr= learning)        
    y_predtrain, running_loss = train_Conv_1D(model, criterion, optimizer, epochs, learning, verbose, train_dl)
    acc_train = accuracy_score(y_train, y_predtrain)
    y_predsubt, y_pred_proba, running_loss = eval_model_a(model, nb_classes, criterion, test_dl)
    acc_test = accuracy_score(y_tests, y_predsubt)
```

And the code with save and re-load model :

```
    train_dl, test_dl = get_data_loaderRN(X_train, y_train, X_tests, y_tests, batch_size) 
    model = Conv_1D(input_shape, nb_classes, num_features, seq_length, batch_size, iter_model, iter_pre, dropout)
    model = model.double()
    model.cuda()
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()  
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr= learning)        
    y_predtrain, running_loss = train_Conv_1D(model, criterion, optimizer, epochs, learning, verbose, train_dl)
    acc_train = accuracy_score(y_train, y_predtrain)
    ## Save model and clean GPU cache + re-seed
    torch.save(model, model_path)
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    torch.manual_seed(my_seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(my_seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    ## Reload model and use it to predict
    model = torch.load(model_path)
    model.to(device)
    y_predsubt, y_pred_proba, running_loss = eval_model_a(model, nb_classes, criterion, test_dl)
    acc_test = accuracy_score(y_tests, y_predsubt)
```

The Save / Clean / Load steps are there to simulate what happened with the model used for daily prediction... and the results are far from those with the original model.

How could I address this problem ?
Thanks in advance for your support.
Best,

NB1. The output is double "y_predsubt" recors the predicted class and "y_pred_proba" records the likelihood associated by the model to each of the 4 classes.

NB2. I did the same with a LSTM model and get the same issue :-(

Answer (score 0):

Two elements I discovered can help others:

1. model.eval() before the prediction with yhat = model(X_test) is a must to secure determinism
2. **for LSTM**, the dropout creates non-deterministic results. Bringing dropout to 0 allowed determinism (but lower accuracy / lower F1 for my classification job)